# doublepointing in mail data section

Tags: php, email

I'm sending email via php sockets and I've the following:

```
fputs($fp, "EHLO your.domain\r\n");
fputs($fp, "AUTH LOGIN\r\n");
fputs($fp, "MAIL FROM:" . $from_mail . "\r\n");
fputs($fp, base64_encode($login) . "\r\n");
fputs($fp, base64_encode($password) . "\r\n");
fputs($fp, "RCPT TO:" . $mail_to . "\r\n");
fputs($fp, "DATA\r\n");

fputs($fp,"Sometext: sometext\r\n");
fputs($fp, $header . "\r\n" . $text . "\r\n.\r\n");
fputs($fp, "QUIT\r\n");
```

But the string `Sometext:sometext` doesn't display in my message body. How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Your MTA is probably ignoring "Sometext:sometext" as an invalid header.  Try "X-Sometext: sometext" instead, and check your mail logs too.

Answer (score 0):

you can use html special chars to do &#58 == :